# How can I inspect jQuery data() in Firefox developer tools?

Tags: jquery, firefox-developer-tools

HTML data attributes can be seen on Inspector tab, but How can I inspect jQuery data() which are set by code like
`$( element ).data( "foo", 52 );`

Thanks for all the answers But I like to know is there a simple way to inspect all jQuery data() of the page like HTML data attributes displaying currently in the inspector tab,

Comment: simple console `$( element ).data( "foo");`

Comment: In the console tab, you can use the above code and it will give you the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

```
$(element).data("foo");
```